# HCM Full Data Sync to FSCM not publishing data

Tags: peoplesoft

I am setting up Integration Broker messaging from HCM 9.2 to FSCM 9.2 using the `PERSON_BASIC_FULLSYNC` service operation (the delivered process) to sync data from HCM to FSCM. I have activated the service operation, handler, queue, and routing on both sides, however when I run the Full Data Publish process, it runs to No Success with the following error:

```
Fetching array element 0: index is not in range 1 to 3. 
(180,252) EOL_PUBLISH.PUBDTL.GBL.default.190 0-01-01.Step05.OnExecute  PCPC:16088  Statement:266
```

I had initially run this process, and it ran to success, however it did not publish any new data in `PS_PERSONAL_DATA` in FSCM, so I updated the service operation version in HCM from 'INTERNAL' to 'VERSION_1', as the corresponding service operation in FSCM only had the 'VERSION_1' version available. But after I change the version so they match, and run the process it goes to No Success.

If I set the version of the service operation in HCM back to 'INTERNAL' and run the process, then it is successful but no data gets published in `PS_PERSONAL_DATA`. Any thoughts on what I should look at?

Comment: Still have the issue, Nick?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a service op. routing problem. Confirm the routing directions and ensure that any alias' that are set don't cause issues. Service Ops on each side need to be the same.